# Desktop wallpaper removed on reboot (Xubuntu 14.10)

Tags: desktop-background

Whenever I restart my computer and log-in my desktop wallpaper of choosing is removed and replaced by a single colored background: before reboot https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSd2B.jpg after reboot https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYurQ.png so far xubuntu/xfce have only meant trouble.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I didn't like your wallpaper (kidding).
When you choose a custom wallpaper you need to make sure not to delete from your hard drive. If you deleted the picture, then that is your issue (do not delete next time).

Comment: No. I did not remove my wallpaper.

Comment: I guess I don't have any answers, sorry.
But I found this link (http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2012/11/xubuntu-1210-day-2-customise-desktop.html), you can check it to see if you have any missing steps.